# Discussion link missing for beta sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51

The Area51 page for proposals already in Beta [(example)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) does not link to related discussion like the pages for not-yet-started proposals do.

That should change, because Betas can well be the subject of important discussion ([example](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/restart-graphic-design-as-design)).

Answer (score 3):

If you check the Definition and Commitment phases, there actually are links for discussion even during the Beta phase. For example, [User Interface](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728?phase=commitment) has [one such discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/user-interface-merge). Remember that in order to be listed, you need to list the *proposal's link* in your Discussion post, not the link to the live site. Nevertheless, I think it's fine that there isn't a big highlight on the Beta tab.

When a site has entered into the Beta phase, discussion about that site should happen *on that site*. The Area 51 Discussion section is great for the ability to connect multiple proposals, but it remains a separate place from the Beta site. Once the users of a site get their own place to discuss, it is often harmful to the site to try and split that particular community to make their discussions in two places. So by not putting the discussions on the Beta tab, it helps consolidate that discussion about the site should now move on to being on the site itself, not to be on Area 51.

From merges like Science Fiction and Fantasy, to concerns about sites like Coffee on Cooking, Area 51 proposal discussions still work on Meta sites. So if you start a wide Area 51 discussion about a site that's in Beta, you should visit that site's Meta and alert them about the discussion happening. More of the community is going to see that because that's where they'll be going for news in their site, not Area 51.